# parse JSON using ajax jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to parse json from jQuery using this:

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'http://localhost:8181/salesmandata/', 
    data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            console.log(element);
        });
    }
});
```

and here's json response:

> {"resultDescription":"SUCCESS","data":[["Oswaldo","21006"],["Mao","52311"],["Angeline","45300"],["Gerardo","36467"],["Nicki","17099"],["Test","28682"]]}

so if i'll do

```
$.each(data, function(index, element) {
                console.log(element);
            });
```

it logs object, success and *[Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2], Array[2]]* which contains data (swaldo, mao etc.)

How can I do that on response I recieve only that array elements? I want to store these elements in chart and I want these in that format:

```
var data=[
        {
            value: 21006,
            name: "Oswaldo"
        } etc..
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The array you want is in the property `data` of the response object `data`

```
var mappedData = data.data.map(function(item){    
   return { value: item[1], name: item[0] };
});
```